# SVG animation along path with Raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I have a rather interesting issue with SVG animation.

I am animating along a circular path using Raphael

```
obj = canvas.circle(x, y, size);
path = canvas.circlePath(x, y, radius);                
path = canvas.path(path); //generate path from path value string
obj.animateAlong(path, rate, false);
```

The circlePath method is one I have created myself to generate the circle path in SVG path notation:

```
Raphael.fn.circlePath = function(x , y, r) {      
  var s = "M" + x + "," + (y-r) + "A"+r+","+r+",0,1,1,"+(x-0.1)+","+(y-r)+" z";   
  return s; 
}
```

So far, so good - everything works. I have my object (obj) animating along the circular path.

BUT:

The animation only works if I create the object at the same X, Y coords as the path itself.

If I start the animation from any other coordinates (say, half-way along the path) the object animates in a circle of the correct radius, however it starts the animation from the object X,Y coordinates, rather than along the path as it is displayed visually.

Ideally I would like to be able to stop/start the animation - the same problem occurs on restart. When I stop then restart the animation, it animates in a circle starting from the stopped X,Y.

**UPDATE**

I created a page that demonstrates the issue:
http://infinity.heroku.com/star_systems/48eff2552eeec9fe56cb9420a2e0fc9a1d3d73fb/demo

Click "start" to start the animation. 
When you stop and re-start the animation, it continues from the current circle coords in a circle of the correct dimensions.

Comment: do you have an example page demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that Raphael has no way of knowing that the circle is already part-way along the path. The "start" function means just that -- start an animation. imo it would be broken if it did anything else.

That said, your use case is a valid one, and might warrant another function -- a 'pause' of some sort. Of course, getting that into trunk would take longer probably than you want to wait.

From the [Raphael source code](http://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.js#L3078), here's what happens when you call 'stop'.

```
Element[proto].stop = function () {
    animationElements[this.id] && animationElements[length]--;
    delete animationElements[this.id];
    return this;
};
```

This decrements the total number of animations, and removes that animation from the list. Here's what the 'pause' function might look like:

```
Element[proto].pause = function () {
    animationElements[this.id] && animationElements[length]--;
    this._paused_anim = animationElements[this.id];
    delete animationElements[this.id];
    return this;
};
```

this saves the animation to be resumed later. then

```
Element[proto].unpause = function () {
    this._paused_anim && (animationElements[this.id]=this._paused_anim);
    ++animationElements[length] == 1 && animation();
    return this;
};
```

would unpause. Given scoping conditions, these two functions might need to be injected right into the Raphael source code (it's core hacking, I know but sometimes there's no alternative). I would put it right below the "stop" function shown above.

Try that, and tell me how it goes.

====EDIT====

Ok, so it looks like you'll have to modify the "start" attribute of animationElements[this.id]... something like:

```
this._pause_time = (+new Date) - animationElements[this.id].start;
```

in the pause, and then

```
animationElements[this.id].start = (+new Date) - this._pause_time;
```

on resume.

http://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.js#L3064

Comment: Cool, cheers. I will try this out.The core issue still remains - the animation will only work when the object starts at the "top" of the circle. If you have a look at the demo, the object should move along the larger dotted circle ...

Comment: Pause works, but the unpause doesn't start the animation. No errors. Think maybe the animation needs to be manually kicked-off again. Delving into the source to work that out ...

Comment: I just modified the "unpause" code; it should be fixed. let me know if it works.

Comment: Interesting ... I added the call to animation() and the issue is now that when you hit unpause, the object restarts the animation from where it would be if you hadn't paused. Something happening in the internals to make it skip ahead (which is smart, I presume this is ensure that the animation remains consistent even if the CPU can't get to every frame on time).

Comment: You're a champion. That got it. I couldn't work out how to get the timestamp set properly. Thanks!

Comment: Yep! Thanks for your help. Not quite what I was looking for but I can bend it to my will now :p

Comment: BTW you should totally send that to Raphael as a patch -- having a 'pause' option out of the box would be very nice.

Comment: `pause` and `resume` methods are now available in Raphael 2.0