# raphael question - using animateAlong

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am using raphael to do some SVG animation and cannot seem to get the function animateAlong to work. I continue to get the error "attrs[0] is undefined" referencing line 3450 of the un-compressed raphael code.

Basically, I create a circle with a given center and then want to animate an image around that path. Here is that simple code:

```
var circle = paper.circle(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius);
```

I then clone an image (since I plan to have a number of these on this path) and place at the edge of the circle:

```
var wheelClone = wheel.clone();
var wheelRadius = parseInt(wheel8ImageWidth/2);
wheelClone
.translate((circleCenterX + circleRadius)-3, circleCenterY-wheelRadius);
```

where I init circleCenterX earlier with circleCenterX = circle.attr(cx);

This all works fine with image placed correctly - but it errors on animateAlong.

I have studied as many examples as i can find and have dissected the documentation but cannot get the hang here.

So, I simply try to call the function but have no earthly idea what the documentation is referring to.  The documentation animates a dot around a path but refers to two variables  - rx and ry which I cannot suss out - both in an init function and then with the callback.

Here is what I have - -  where the rx and ry and just made up as I have no idea what they refer to.

```
 var wheelAttr = {
  rx: 5,
  ry: 3
 };

 wheelClone.attr(wheelAttr).animateAlong(circle, 2000, true, function() {
  wheel.attr({rx: 4, ry: 4});
 });
```

My current jsFiddle is a bit of a mess at the moment and I can clean it up, but I suspect that there is some obvious thing here?

Thanks to all

S

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a circle is actually a valid path (i.e, something you can pass to animateAlong()). I think you need to create a path that is circular. See the following:

[svg-animation-along-path-with-raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627436/svg-animation-along-path-with-raphael)

Hopefully, it will help.