# Why is my Animate alone broken?

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael, line, curve

Using the Raphael.js I have made a circle and a path, all I wanted to do was make the circle animate alone the path, as if the center of the circle went along the line.

http://jsfiddle.net/rEJNJ/3/

Can anyone offer some advice

```
window.onload = function () {
            var paper = Raphael("canvas", 640, 480);
            var c = paper.circle(90, 90, 40);
                c.attr({fill: "blue"});
            var p = paper.path("M150,380 C150,360 50,250 220,90").attr({stroke: "#ff0000"});

            c.animateAlong(p, 4000, true);
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation works if you create your circle with the same X/Y coordinates as the beginning of the path:

http://jsfiddle.net/rEJNJ/4/

```
window.onload = function () {
    var paper = Raphael("canvas", 640, 480);
    var c = paper.circle(150, 380, 40).attr({fill: "blue"});
    var p = paper.path("M150,380 C150,360 50,250 220,90").attr({stroke: "#ff0000"});
    c.animateAlong(p, 4000, true);
};
```

Take a look at this post for some insight as to why: [SVG animation along path with Raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627436/svg-animation-along-path-with-raphael)

Comment: Ah thanks. Sorry I'm new to javascript really. I'm mostly a designer, but I'm interested in code. Thank you, you've helped me solve one of my many other questions too.